# Designing a low-tech, clockwork-like automatic timer via powered winch and pulley system

Tags: pulleys

I'm trying to design a fictional winch and pulley system that, in its basic form, is a weight tied to a rope, that goes through a pulley, which then attaches to a powered winch: the winch turns, winds the rope, and the weight is lifted. OK, easy peasy! What I then want to happen is for the winch to release once the weight reaches a certain height, at which point the weight will fall more-or-less freely down thanks to gravity. The complication is that the power source for the winch is constant (i.e. a waterwheel powered by a waterfall) and therefore the belt driving it will be continuously doing so. The goal is to exploit this by having the winch re-engage and begin the process of lifting and dropping the weight all over again, effectively creating an automated timer with the weight rising and falling at regular intervals.

And so, my question is "What kind of mechanism would be required to have this winch disengage and allow the rope to unspool, while remaining attached to its constantly-rotating base, and then furthermore lock back into place once the weight has dropped in order to re-spool the rope again?" Is such a thing even possible? And if not, could you tell me why? I'm quite interested in learning.

My knowledge about these things is, sadly, not advanced, but I have given it a lot of thought. I feel like the way to trigger the winch's release would be some kind of ceiling to block the weight's rise, thus causing the winch to stall, or perhaps some kind of lever that the rising weight would activate. But, then this is the point where the best I seem to be able to come up with for the next step is "and then some stuff happens." I feel like springs and ratchets would factor in, somehow, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how they would be arranged and applied. I'm just flailing at this point.

My sincerest apologies if this is overly basic, or just plain stupid, but I'm really struggling to find answers. Thanks so much for your time♥︎

Comment: A lever to disconnect a dog clutch.

Comment: Look at  watch mechanical mechanisms, wrist watches but especially those big hanging fancy wall clocks where all the gears are exposed for show. Also...mechanical music boxes which just involve something slowly spinning with features on the surface that hit different things as it spins to mechanically sequence something.